# How to delete vertex on AgensGraph?

Tags: vertex, agens-graph

I want to delete vertex on AgensGraph.

```
agens=# create (:v1{id:1})-[:e1{id:2}]->(:v1{id:3});
GRAPH WRITE (INSERT VERTEX 2, INSERT EDGE 1)
agens=# match (n:v1{id:1}) delete n;
ERROR:  vertices with edges can not be removed
```

But, there is an error on it.

How to delete vertex on AgensGraph?

Answer (score 0):

Use DETACH before DELETE.

```
agens=# match (n:v1{id:1}) detach delete n;
GRAPH WRITE (DELETE VERTEX 1, DELETE EDGE 1)
```